# Deleting items in a csv file?

Tags: csv

I have an .csv with four or five columns of data for webstats.

I analyzed the data with a program how I wanted to, and now I have a text file with a list of the pages I want and I'd like to delete all of the data for every page I don't need, so that only the ones from the text file remain.

i.e. If I have the .csv as follows:

```
/fruits-and-veggies/apples    16    3    03:43    .72%
/fruits-and-veggies/pears    8    2    02:34    .65%
/fruits-and-veggies/broccoli    6    5    04:23    .87%
/fruits-and-veggies/asparagus    46    6    01:23    .77%
/fruits-and-veggies/passion-fruit    36    7    05:53    .74%
```

And I have the text file as follows:

```
/fruits-and-veggies/apples
/fruits-and-veggies/pears
/fruits-and-veggies/passion-fruit
```

How do I manipulate the excel file so it only reads:

```
/fruits-and-veggies/apples    16    3    03:43    .72%
/fruits-and-veggies/pears    8    2    02:34    .65%
/fruits-and-veggies/passion-fruit    36    7    05:53    .74%
```

I've heavily researched this topic and have yet to come up with a viable solution. I'm using Windows XP, and batch files are favored if its possible, but I really don't know where start.

Comment: May I please ask what are you using to manipulatexcel file? Do you want to do it programmatically or using excel functions?

Comment: I'm using a batch file to read in the page names (after physically copying and pasting that column to a designated 'input' text file) and spit out the ones that share a characteristic I need (that they belong to one category rather than another, they all share the same header tag). I would like to do it programmatically if possible. It can also be a .csv if it makes the job easier, no preference.

Comment: Its possible to do it programmatically, if you are familiar with .net (c# or vb) you can write a program which does all the above, you can read file names and you can use a third part library to manipulate excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use python and its regular-expression module.  It actually even has  CSV module if I am not mistaken.  There are many other ways / tools to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I work with complex table (csv) manipulations daily, and my work has been greatly eased by the amazing python petl library.  Once you use this, there is no going back, and the author of the library is very helpful if you ever get stuck.

If you are not a programmer,don't worry - with even minimal scripting skills you can do amazing things with csv, text, json, and whatever is in table formats using petl.

Check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0FleNEcO9I

Library is here: http://petl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

If you want to try and get stuck, ping me and I'll help you out.

Cheers,

PJ